# How to pull an CouchApp from CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I've created and saved a view document in an CouchApp from within CouchDB.

Is there a way to pull that data in the same way as pushing apps?

**Push**

```
couchapp push http://domain.tld:5984/databasename
```

**Pull**

```
couchapp pull http://domain.tld:5984/databasename
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `couchapp clone http://domain.tld:5984/databasename/_design/ddoc_name myapp` 
More about at [Get started](http://couchapp.org/page/getting-started) and [Usage](http://couchapp.org/page/couchapp-usage) pages.

Comment: To clarify I pushed up parts of the app via ´couchapp push´ and then added some views via futon, then I want to pull that code down. Should I use clone in that case to?

Comment: yes, `clone` command is about retrieving design documents from CouchDB to filesystem.